# Inline delegate declaration (c#)

Tags: c#, delegates

I can't get the following to compile:

```
var x = new Action(delegate void(){});
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You don't specify a return type when using anonymous methods. This would work:

```
var x = new Action(delegate(){});
```

Some alternatives:

```
Action x = () => {}; // Assuming C# 3 or higher
Action x = delegate {};
Action x = delegate() {};
var x = (Action) (delegate{});
```

Comment: @maxp, you can also use syntax such as `Action x = delegate() {};` - both being same so use as per your likings!

Comment: @leppie: I don't like it either, but it's the minimal change required to make the OP's code compile :) I'll offer some alternatives...

Answer (score 20):

Why not lambda notation?

```
Action myAction= (Action)(()=>
{
});
```

Comment: Can simplify to `Action myAction = () => { };`?